# Corrigir o erro no XML

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Meus apps feitos no Android Studio 2.2.2 dão erro de XML. As classes ficam como que não declaradas. Eu já ate fiz uma pergunta dessas aqui, mas não tinha o erro especificado. o erro que aparece no Logcat é esse:

> `Invalid ranges during formatting in Language: XML`

Comment: Precisamos do código. Além disso, o LogCat não é relevante se o erro é de compilação. Precisamos do que aparece na aba "Messages", que é a saída de erros do Gradle.

Comment: De qual código vc esta falando Pablo. Porque na aba message não aparece nada de errado..diz que tudo esta bem...mas as classes aparecem em vermelho com se não estivesses declaradas. ate agora ninguém conseguiu descobrir o erro.

Comment: Pode colocar uma captura de tela disso? Mostre o que aparece logo após tentar compilar.

Comment: como eu disse na aba messagem não tem erro. mas olhem onde esta a seta. isso é um erro de xml pq ele nao reconhece a Activity.

Answer (score 1):

É difícil precisar exatamente o que está acontecendo com as poucas informações que estão disponíveis, mas olhando um exemplo que eu tinha, o que eu posso te sugerir é trocar o nome da atividade ali dentro do Manifest para:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
```

Não é necessário o nome do pacote, talvez isto que esteja dando pau. Talvez esta resposta fosse mais apropriada para um comentário mas não tenho reputação suficiente.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: vc ajudou muito, qualquer comentário ou sugestão são bem vindos

Comment: @Legolas se a resposta deu certo por favor aceite, assim quem vier no site no futuro sabe que ao usar essa estrategia consegue resolver o problema (: E fico feliz que deu certo

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do leofontes está correta. A forma como você esta declarando esta "completa demais", quando fica redundante o android studio recusa como erro, porque essa declaração completa ele faz sozinho.
Outra coisa que acontece muito comigo é a necessidade de reescrever as classes ou tags quando eu copio e colo o código de um lugar para outro, não entendo porque mas mesmo estando correto o android acusa erro e depois que eu reescrevo some. Tenta isso também, reescreve, fecha o Android Studio e vê se some o erro.. De qualquer forma a colocação da activity dada pelo leofontes está correta, usa ela e testa.

Comment: Ramon, fiz como vc falou..e deu certo...valeu irmão.